# Shell Script : How to put multi value of variable in the same line with special model

Tags: shell, unix, sed, paste

I have the following data in multiple lines for $test_Data:

```
echo "$test_Data"

test1
test2
test3
test4
```

And

```
echo $test_Data

test1 test2 test3 test4
```

What I want to do is to convert the value of test_Data with in one line like this model

```
echo $test_Data 

'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'
```

Please Help
Thanks you

Comment: Do you want to change the value of test_Data to `'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'`, or do you want to change it to `'test1',\n'test2',\n'test3',\n'test4'\n`?  Either way, the echo will give you the output you want.  Or, do you not want to change the value of the variable at all, but you just want to filter it to generate the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
echo "$test_Data" | sed "s/.*/'&'/;N;s/\n/,&/;P;D;"
```

- `s/.*/'&'/`: enclose whole line with quotes
- `N;s/\n/,&/;P;D;`: merge lines and replace new line character with comma

To output on a single line:

```
echo "$test_Data" | sed -E "s/.*/'&/;:a;N;s/\n/','/;$ s/$/'/;ba;"
```

Comment: You can use echo $test_Data | sed "s/ /', '/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/". Without the " the \n go out.

Answer (score 0):

with BASH script :

```
#!/bin/bash


test_Data="test1
test2
test3
test4"



echo "$test_Data" | sed -e "s/^/'/g" | sed "s/$/'/"| awk '{printf "%s" $1","}'|sed "s/,$//"
```

result

```
[$h311] ➤ ./multi.bash
'test1','test2','test3','test4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simply with bash

```
echo "'${test_Data//$'\n'/\',\'}'"
```

Comment: Nice one... but I don't see any Bash tag here.

Comment: @SLePort with sh I got sh : 10: Bad substitution, it's the // which is bash specific.